# SharePoint Syntax Error for calculated column

Tags: calculated-columns, sharepoint-list

I am trying to use a string of IF statements to be able to assign a value to for a calculated column in my SharePoint list. This column will display values based on what a date column reads. The column is supposed to read a value based on if its expired, about to expire, up to date, or never certified. he expiration date is a year later from what the date column reads.

Here is my code

`=IF(ISBLANK([Column_Name]), "Never Certified", IF(Today()-[Column_Name])>=365, "Expired",IF(AND((Today()-[Column_Name])>=335, IF(Today()-[Column_Name]) <=365), "Expires Soon",  IF((Today()-[Column_Name]) <=335, "Up to Date", "Error")))))`

I've tried a few different things, by switching around parenthesis and I keep getting this syntax error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hF3p.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this formula for your SharePoint calculated column:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Column_Name]),"Never Certified",IF(Today()-[Column_Name]>=365,"Expired",IF(Today()-[Column_Name]>=335,"Expires Soon",IF(Today()-[Column_Name] <=335,"Up to Date","Error"))))
```

---

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (it is based on language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).
2. Use correct *display name* of your SharePoint columns in above formula.
3. Wrap column names inside `[]` if your column name has space in it. For example: `[My Column Name]`.

**Official Documentations**:

1. [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14))